# Add one to a number upto per second

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

How to make a program that will add one to a number per second until it becomes 500 using html , javascript , jQuery ? Thanks in Advance.

Comment: `setInterval(function() { variable++; }, 1000);`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
var c = 0,                                     // Start counter at 0
    ticker = null;                             // Setup inverval var

function tick() {
   if (c>=500) return clearInterval( ticker ); // End if == or > 500
   ++c;                                        // Else... increment
   console.log( c ); // 1... ...500            // Use your c variable
}

setInterval( tick, 1000 );                     // Start and loop every 1000ms
```